# “How to fix error C4996: '_strupr': ’ error in c++”

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I follow the instruction change the `strupr` to `_strupr` and the give other erro, then I change to `_strupr_s`, but it said

> argument type are char *

can anyone give a help?

```
// interpreter.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cctype>
#include "Interpreter.h"
using namespace std;

double Statement::findValue(char *id)   //Return the  value
{
IdNode tmp(id);
list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
if (i != idList.end())
    return i->value;
else
    issueError("unknown variable");
return 0;
}
void Statement::processNode(char *id, double e) //Update the value or add it to the list
{
IdNode tmp(id, e);
list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
if (i != idList.end())
    i->value = e;
else
    idList.push_front(tmp);
 }
 void Statement::readId(char *id)  //Read input into an array
{
int i = 0;
if (isspace(ch))
    cin >> ch;
if (isalpha(ch)){ //If it is a letter, save the subsequent numbers or letters.
    while (isalnum(ch)){
        id[i++] = ch;
        cin.get(ch);
    }
    id[i] = '\0';
}
else
    issueError("Identifier expected");
}
double Statement::factor()  //Factor processing
{
double var, minus = 1.0;
static char id[200];
cin >> ch;
while (ch == '+' || ch == '-'){ //Is the symbol before the number
    if (ch == '-')   //Determine positive and negative
        minus *= -1.0;
    cin >> ch;
}
if (isdigit(ch) || ch == '.'){   //number
    cin.putback(ch);
    cin >> var >> ch; //save vaule
}
else if (ch == '('){ //Equal to the left parenthesis to handle the expression inside the parentheses
    var = expression(); //Recursively processing expressions in parentheses
    if (ch == ')')   //The right parenthesis continues to process ch
        cin >> ch;
    else
        issueError("right paren left out");
}
else{
    readId(id);
    if (isspace(ch))
        cin >> ch;
    var = findValue(id);
}
return minus * var;
}
double Statement::term()
{
double f = factor();
while (true){
    switch (ch){
    case '*':
        f *= factor();
        break;
    case '/':
        f /= factor();
        break;
    default:
        return f;
    }
  }
 }
double Statement::expression()
{
double t = term();
while (true){
    switch (ch){
    case '+':
        t += term();
        break;
    case '-':
        t -= term();
        break;
    default:
        return t;
    }
}
}
void Statement::getStatement()
{
char id[20];
char command[20];
double e;
cout << "enter a statement: ";
cin >> ch;
readId(id);
_strupr_s(strcpy(command, id));
if (strcmp(command, "STATUS") == 0)
    cout << *this;
if (strcmp(command, "PRINT") == 0){
    readId(id);
    cout << id << " = " << findValue(id) << endl;
}
else if (strcmp(command, "END") == 0)
    exit(0);
else{
    if (isspace(ch))
        cin >> ch;
    if (ch == '='){
        e = expression();
        if (ch != ';')
            issueError("there are some extras in the statement. ");
        else
            processNode(id, e);
    }
    else
        issueError("'=' is missing");
}
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Statement &s)
{
list<IdNode>::const_iterator i = s.idList.begin();
for (; i != s.idList.end(); i++)
    out << *i;
out << endl;
return out;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const IdNode &r)
{
out << r.id << " = " << r.value << endl;
return out;
}

int main()
{
Statement statement;
cout << "the program processes statements  of the following format:\n"
    << "\t<id> = <expr>;\n\tprint <id>\n\tstatus\n\tend\n\n";
while (true)
    statement.getStatement();

return 0;
}


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Comment: strupr_s either needs array size as second argument or array of size known in compile time (which you don't have as you do strcpy). So add sizeof(command) or better _countof(command) as second argument. Documentation is your best friend in this business and which overloads exist can be seen on MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strupr-s-strupr-s-l-mbsupr-s-mbsupr-s-l-wcsupr-s-wcsupr-s-l?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strupr-s-strupr-s-l-mbsupr-s-mbsupr-s-l-wcsupr-s-wcsupr-s-l?view=vs-2019), `_strupr_s` is defined as:

```
errno_t _strupr_s(
   char *str,
   size_t numberOfElements
);
```

Your code calls the function as:

```
_strupr_s(strcpy(command, id));
```

You are leaving off the second argument: `size_t numberOfElements`

Comment: hi, when I execute the code and enter the statement and want to print the result, the terminate just close and show these message                                      The thread 0x8a4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3d48 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x810 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[5964] interpreter.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Comment: Now that you have it compiling and running, you'll need to debug it.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @YongmingLiu  The `_s` functions usually crash the program if the operation runs past  `numberOfElements` to make bugs hard to miss, so start by making sure the size is correct. Visual Studio has a debugging utility that will allow you to inspect the program's behaviour at a pretty fine degree. You can step the program until it terminates to see what happened. It may even halt for you when terminate is called allowing you to inspect the backtrace (usually one of the tabs down at the bottom of the window while debugging) to see how the program got into such a bad state.